# Bash.exe in Visual Studio post-build processor

Tags: bash, visual-studio

I'm trying to call a script via bash.exe in the post-build events from visual studio (actually atmel studio 7.0, which is based on vs)

I'm getting the following error when i try this:

```
"$(SystemRoot)\System32\bash.exe"
```

The following error is reported:

> Task "Exec"
> "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"
>
> '"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command,         operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Vs\Avr.common.targets(36,5): error: MSB3073:
> The command ""C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" " exited with code 9009.

I even tried copying bash.exe to another destination, but that had the same problem.

Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: Try the solution mentioned in [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1105)

Answer (score 0):

solution found here: https://gist.github.com/m93a/cb41dcbd72ee7ff9fea3726a28d9f895

don't call bash.exe directly, but call this .bat file instead